ng2-file-upload: Avoid uploading file using FormData
I am using the g2-file-upload library to upload a file to an S3 bucket via a signed URL. However, the issue is that g2-file-upload always uses the formData: { file: binary } format in the upload request.
How can I prevent g2-file-upload from using formData and instead send the file as raw data in the request body? I haven't been able to find any configuration in ng2-file-upload to disable the use of formData.

I was able to do that with setting the disableMultipart to true, in that way library will not add the FormData, and then I set the binary file with formatDataFunction.
